# Accidentally removed pacct file

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage

I see that the `/var` is occupied upto `99%` and observed that the `pacct` file has occupied 13G and tried copying to other directory and then accidentally did `rm pacct` post that I did

`>  pacct` as per [this article](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2224237-redhat-linux-can-i-delete-pacct-log)

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/RootVg-var        20G   20G  233M  99% /var
```

even after the clearing space i see the same output

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/RootVg-var        20G   20G  233M  99% /var
```

```
[root]# du -hs /var
7.6G    /var
```

```
[root var]# du -hs *
272K    account
8.0K    adm
355M    cache
0       crash
8.0K    db
0       empty
0       games
0       gopher
0       kerberos
116M    lib
0       local
0       lock
3.9G    log
0       mail
0       nis
369M    opt
0       preserve
0       run
2.9G    spool
4.0K    tmp
0       VRTSat_lhc
0       VRTSpbx
0       yp
```

should i restart the pacct service to make sure the changes reflect ?

Can anyone please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by doing the following steps

```
# touch /var/account/pacct
# chown root /var/account/pacct
# chmod 0644 /var/account/pacct 
# accton /var/account/pacct
```

as written [in the article](https://www.ucartz.com/clients/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/1149/How-to-StartorStop-and-EnableorDisable-process-accounting-psacct.html)